# comparing all the values of a column if condition is met

Tags: awk

I have a file with 4 columns. Columns 2 and 4 have numbers.

```
a 55  k 3
b 59 l 3
c 79 m 277
d 255 n 277
e 257 o 267
f 267 p 287
g 290  q 287
h 290 r 287
i 310 s 900
```

I need to compare all the rows of column 2 with those in column 4, not limited to same rows, and select only those rows in column 4, where values in column 4 are greater than those in column 2 in a range of 1 to 30. For example, row 3 in column 4 will also be selected because it has difference in same range with values in column 2 in rows 4,5,6. A possible output from sample file fulfilling above condition may be like below.

```
m 277
n 277
o 267
p 287
q 287
r 287
```

Sorry if I did not present my problem clearly, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=30;++i) feasible[i+$2]=1;} {val[NR] = $4; letter[NR] = $3} END {for(y in val) if(feasible[val[y]]) print letter[y], val[y]}'
```

Basically, you keep track of all feasible values for the fourth column.  You also keep track of the third and fourth columns of data.  Then, at the end, you check each value and see if they are feasible

Comment: Nice solution, provided the numbers don't get ridiculously huge =)

Comment: @paddy If that's a concern, you can just store the value and explicitly compute the difference.  That however requires a nested loop.

Comment: +1 I agree with @Barmar. I was lost after reading `I have a file …`

Comment: @Barmar and JS웃, sorry this sure was tedious read  and I realize its sloppy.